# How to join chain link and wooden fence?

Tags: fence

A tree fell and destroyed one corner of the chain link fence between my neighbor's yard and my yard. The neighbor replaced their portion of the fence with a wooden fence, but their new fence isn't aligned with my fence anymore (I assume they were worried about building it too close to the ditch running behind our houses). So now there's about a 5 foot gap between the end of my chain link fence and the outside corner of their wooden fence.

What are my options to fill that gap? Should I just put a metal post as close to that corner as I can? Or can I attach the chain link fence directly to the wooden post somehow (assuming the neighbor is ok with that)? How do I connect the tension bar to the wooden post?

[image: The fence]

Comment: Depends on what the post looks like.

Comment: It's just a plain square wooden post, either 4x4 or 6x6 (can't remember).

Comment: I might use the standard bar down the last link as you would with a steel post and use 3 or 4 lag bolts to connect to the post with the straps on the side of the post it’s a short span so should not be under two much tension.

Comment: This is really a matter of prerogative, or at least too broad. You haven't posed a clear problem statement. There are many ways to connect a tension bar to the wooden post, such as U-straps, but we don't know if you want to do that. Pick a direction and ask about any _specific_ challenges you encounter.

Comment: POB? By who;) they should be kicked out of DiY if they think there's any other way then doing this right. *Just screw it to the fence, sure.* Yeah, no. - Put a Post.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the metal post designed to work with the chain link fence, however, here is a [youTube example of how to attach chain link to wood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZE2rKochBg).  As you can see, it does not look particularly great.

Comment: I would not link to a hack job I fast forward to find the example and he was using drywall screws that were two long for an exterior gate and grinding the tips off never saw the example.

Comment: +1. I'm not even going to watch the video; I've *never* seen that, and I never want to. 5' isn't a gap; it's an entire section of fence.

Comment: indeed, maybe 5' is a gap if you farm elephants!